# How to use object literal to run a function

Tags: javascript, breeze, object-literal

Im trying to use an object literal to select which query I want to run. strategy on the getCategories function is always undefined. What is the proper way to do this? I dont want to pass a string and then do an if else.

categories.js

```
    activate = function () {
        datacontext.getCategories(categories, datacontext.Fetch.FromCacheThenServer);
    },
```

datacontext.js

```
    var  Fetch = {
        'FromCache': executeLocalQuery,
        'FromServer': executeServerQuery,
        'FromCacheThenServer': executeCacheThenServerQuery
    },

    getCategories = function (observable, strategy) {
        var query = breeze.EntityQuery
            .from("Categories")
            .orderBy('Order');
            Fetch.strategy(query)
    }

    executeCacheThenServerQuery(query) {
        //query code
    }
```

Comment: And how are you including `datacontext.js` in `categories.js`? Javascript isn't Python, there is no `datacontext.getCategories` unless you manually assign it that way. Otherwise it's just `getCategories`.

Comment: Im using Durandal.  categories.js has datacontext = require('modules/'datacontext')